# Minecraft 1.14.4 Functions not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

In Minecraft 1.14.4, I am trying to learn to make simple functions, but I can't find any information about how to fix the problem I am having.

My files are in

```
<world name>\datapacks\<datapack name>\data\<namespace>\functions\<function>.mcfunction
```

After I do `/reload` and `/function namespace:function-name` it says

```
Unknown function <namespace>:<function name>
```

I have my pack.mcmeta file in the "datapack-name" folder with the following code:

```
{
  "pack": {
    "pack_format": 1,
    "description": "Test Datapack"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try quitting the world and re-enter?

Comment: Yes, it is just still causing the same error message to appear.

Comment: Are you able to send your whole data pack?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the function has to be free of syntax errors, otherwise the entire datapack doesn't load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problem causing errors:

- Do you have a slash in any of your functions?
- Are you function names written with letters which aren't in the
  Alphabet (maybe _ or -) ?
- Have you already tried every command ingame directly?

Some solutions:

- Remove any slashes before the commands, else the function wouldn't be recognized ingame
- Call every function only with letter of the alphabet
- Try every command ingame first, then copy it to the function an remove the slash
- Try making an function which only run 'say hello world', if this doesn't work, something with your packstructure is false

Hope I could help you